# Adding custom scrape metrics for prometheus in kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have helm installed from prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack.

My pods : -

[image]

> I have created custom yaml file and copied the contents of https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L2521 and appended my custom scrape values in the additionalScrapeConfigs section of the file

Ran the below command to get the values loaded into my Prometheus pod.

[image]

But when i check the Prometheus pod yaml file changes are not reflecting.

I have created custom yaml file and copied the contents of https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L2521 and appended my custom scrape values in the additionalScrapeConfigs section of the file

Ran the below command to get the values loaded into my Prometheus pod.

> helm upgrade --values custom.yml  prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack

But when i check the Prometheus pod yaml after the helm upgrade changes are not reflecting.

i want to see something like below in my prometheus yaml file scrape config of the Prometheus pod

```
> my global config
> global:
> scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
> evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
> scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).
> 
> Alertmanager configuration
> alerting:
> alertmanagers:
> static_configs:
> targets:
> alertmanager:9093
> 
> Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
> rule_files:
>  
>   
> 
> A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
> Here it's Prometheus itself.
> scrape_configs:
> The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
> job_name: "prometheus"
> 
> metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
> scheme defaults to 'http'.
> 
> static_configs:
> targets: ["localhost:9090","x.x.x.x:9095","a.b.c.d:8095"]
```